# Android, displaying message for x seconds

Tags: android, canvas, time, 2d

I want to add a "Game over" and a "level complete" message if my character dies/completes level. What happens right now when he dies/completes level is I end the MainThread and start up the EndScreen-activity/LevelComplete-activity.

But before these activities start I want a message to come up over the screen, preferably an image so I can add some cool text, for a certain amount of seconds, lets say 3 seconds.

Do I really need to start a splash-like activity or a timerTask for this or can it be done in a simpler way?

example:

```
    if(characterHP <= 0){
        stopUpdating();
        showMessage(3, gameOverBitmap);
        startEndScreenActivity();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also customize the look, text, font, position, layout and time (long or short) of a standard Android `Toast` Notification.  (by provide a custom layout, style, or view).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

If you want something more customizable you could overlay an activity or dialog, or even just a view.  However, `Toast` notifications are basically designed for this.

Comment: you wouldnt know the "FLAG" needed to start a new intent ontop of the game if game is 500x500 and the new intent that is started ontop of this is on a 300x300 .png image background. so that the game is still shown behind this intent. Might not have done a good job explaining that :P

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by flag/intent -- all that's needed for a Toast notification is the currently displayed `Activity`.  However, maybe there is something missing with my answer due to lack of OpenGL ES / canvas knowledge?  Does a toast not show above a Canvas?

Comment: nevermind, that question had nothing to do with my original question. Just trying to figure out how to add one activity on top of another without deleting the old one. ^^ Your answer is perfect so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler or something of the sort

```
    if(characterHP <= 0){
    stopUpdating();
    showMessage(3, gameOverBitmap);
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          startEndScreenActivity();   
          }
    }, 3000);
```

The other thing is if you keep track of time passing in your game (I normally do), along with the delta time, then you could make some variant of your own way

```
    long showtime;
    boolean Ending = false;


    if(characterHP <= 0){
    stopUpdating();
    showMessage(3, gameOverBitmap);
    showtime = sytem.gettimemillisecs();
    Ending = true;
```

and then somewhere else:

```
    if (Ending && System.gettimemilisecs > showtime + 3000) {
        startEndScreenActivity();
    }
```

Comment: the second solution makes alot of sence to me, think Ill try that, thank you :)

Comment: though you will need to be updating somewhere for you to know when to end the game, so maybe if you aren't "updating" you should be checking when to switch activities.

Comment: didnt think of that, thats a problem. I want the game to stop, the message to show, then after a delay I want the endScreen to come up..

Comment: maybe I could add a boolean AllowMoving = true; and only render when this is true, then when my character dies, I set it to false so you cant move things on screen anymore but the thread is still running. and the method that draws my "Gmae-over" message isnt effected by this boolean so it will still be drawn before thread ends.

Comment: Perfect, just use a boolean like that :) maybe even the same boolean Ending. if Ending draw ending{} else draw normal game{}

Comment: uff, did not give a good effect, the characters that were moving start flickering, and the "if(ending && System.currentTimeMillis() > showtime + 3000)" never gets called. bah such a stupid problem to have ^^ Im useless whent it comes to delays/timers

Comment: actually got it to semi-work. I cant stop updating game so you can still move the character around while the "game over image is up. but its way better then the flickering it got when I stopped the rendering

Comment: can you put the user input in a boolean? if(!ending) {Do Movement}

Comment: trying that now, kinda works, only problem is that the bullets that are alrdy on screen dosnt go away. But Ill keep trying, getting close ^^